# How can I trim the string before first white space in a series Python text data?

Tags: python, nlp, data-analysis, text-classification, data-cleaning

In this Data I want to trim the string which is code before first white space. And also want to remove the string after "IN" character in python.
Here there is a simple example. I have a column in pandas like this.

```
line = ["RCI-AMG-3664 Laboratory Specialist","RCI-VBC-09568 Administrative Assistant in Cary, NC"]
```

Comment: Can you give a proper example, what are you trying to achieve? Here 'IN' is an abbreviation or you are talking about the **in** before some place name?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are reading the text line by line and saving each line in a string? If you have saved one line in a string "a",

```
a[a.find(' ')+1:]
```

Will return only the part of the string after the first white space.

**Edit** User clarified the lines are in a pandas series. In that case, the above still works, but we need to apply it to the series as such:

```
string_formatter = lambda a: a[a.find(' ')+1:]
your_series = your_series.apply(string_formatter) 
//this will cause the series to cut each string up to the first whitespace
```

If the series can contain objects other than strings, you need to add a type check in the function.

Comment: Hi, andrea. Thanks. Here the data is a series.

Comment: you mean the data is in a pandas.Series object?

Comment: Yes, It is in pandas object

Comment: Ok, @NiraliKhoda I updated the answer to work on a pandas series containing strings.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use regex for data preprocessing.
- you can perform **remove_noise** function in *series also by pandas apply function*.

---

```
import re

def remove_noise(data):
    ans = re.sub('\s+',' ',data)
    ans = re.sub('\sin\s.*','',data)
    ans = data.split(' ')
    del(data[0])
    ans = ' '.join(map(str, data))
    return ans;
```

Comment: If possible add **text data** as input instead of **image** in your question that will be easy for testing.